# What does "CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer" mean?

Tags: c, debugging, buffer, heap-memory

I am having trouble with this code. It breaks at the free(q->izv) function and i get a debug error saying:

```
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer
```

I have no idea what that means so i would be grateful for any help I get.

```
    typedef struct izvodjaci{
        char *izv;
        int broj;
        struct izvodjaci *sled;
    }IZV;

    obrisi_i(IZV *p){
        while (p){
            IZV *q;
            q = p;
            p = p->sled;
            if (!strcmp(q->izv,"UNKNOWN")) free(q->izv);
            free(q);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Chances are this is just where the buffer overflow is just detected and not where it actually occurs. Try to reduce your entire code to a small sample that replicates the issue and post it here, assuming you don't find the issue first.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> What does “CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer” mean?

Suppose you allocate a heap buffer:

```
char* buffer = malloc(5);
```

OK, `buffer` now points to five chars on the heap.

Suppose you write six chars into that buffer:

```
buffer[0] = 'a';
buffer[1] = 'b';
buffer[2] = 'c';
buffer[3] = 'd';
buffer[4] = 'e';
buffer[5] = '\0';
```

You have now corrupted the heap; you were only allowed to write five chars and you wrote six.

The program is now permitted to do *anything whatsoever*. It can work normally, it can crash, it can send all your passwords to hackers in China, **anything**.

Your implementation apparently chooses the best possible choice, which is "inform you that you made a mistake". You should be **very, very happy** that this is what happened, instead of any of the horrible alternatives. Unfortunately it informs you *when the buffer is freed*, and not *when you made the mistake*, but be happy that you got an error at all.

Comment: Thank you. You were right. I miscalculated and i used one space more than i allocated.

Comment: I rewrote almost everything except that... This is the first time i made that mistake so i haven't seen that error message before so i kinda panicked.And thanks for the tips.

Comment: Hi Eric, this was amazing. I kinda used strlen while copying from src char* to dest char*. Can you tell me why Visual Studio compiler finds this corruption issue during free, instead of while I ended up writing out of the memory bounds.

Comment: @user1874627: This is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code, and what you've got there is a specific question about actual code, so I encourage you to (1) search to see if it is answered already, and if not (2) post a question!

Comment: @user1874627: That said, think about it like this: suppose you are developing a compiler for a C-like language. Describe to me how you would implement the feature you are suggesting: detection of out-of-bounds writes to an arbitrary place in an arbitrary memory buffer at the time of writing. The feature cannot be implemented by *magic*; you have to generate *code* for it. What would that code look like?  It doesn't have to be at the assembly code level; try describing it in terms of a high-level language.

Comment: @user1874627: If you're having trouble getting started, here's an easier problem. Suppose you were generating code for detection of out-of-bounds writes to an arbitrary offset in a memory buffer, **but you know that the offset is from the start of the buffer**. How would you write the out-of-bounds-on-write detection in that case?  Both problems are solvable but this one is much easier.