# Issues with destructor/freeing memory

Tags: c++, class, memory, destructor

So I'm pretty new to c++ and i'm trying out some basic dynamic memory allocation and i already run into some issues with it. I'm not really sure what im doing wrong, but I cant run following code:

Class declaration:

```
class Car {
    double maxSpeed;
    bool isNew;
    char* manufacturerName;

public:
    Car(double = 0, bool = true, char* = "Unknown");
    ~Car();
    Car& operator=(const Car&);


};
```

Constructor implementation:

```
Car::Car(double maxSpeed, bool isNew, char* manufacturerName) {
    this->maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    this->isNew = isNew;
    this->manufacturerName = new char[strlen(manufacturerName)];
    strcpy(this->manufacturerName, manufacturerName);
}
```

Destructor implementation:

```
Car::~Car() {
    delete [] manufacturerName;
}
```

Main:

```
int main() {

    Car C(250.0, true, "Name1");
    Car C1(180.0, false, "Name2");
    Car C2;    
    cout << C << C1 << C2;

    return 0;
}
```

error message i get:

[image: error i get]

Comment: have you heard of std::string? or is this one of these crappy university assignments where you have to program in "C inside classes" and forever be a bad C++ developer?

Comment: Yeah, it's an university assignment and i have to use C-style strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039299/what-does-crt-detected-that-the-application-wrote-to-memory-after-end-of-heap-b)

Comment: manufacturerName should be set to `new char[strlen(manufacturerName) + 1]`

Comment: yep, I knew it.

Comment: Oh, of course. My bad. Thank you for spotting it. Problem solved

Comment: @MaciejSobczynski The "university assignment" gave you an incomplete version of a `Car` class.  The copy constructor is missing from the declaration.  Also, problems will arise if `nullptr` is passed as the third argument to the `Car` constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to allocate strlen(...)+1 bytes for your string in constructor to acommodate for the ending zero byte. You are writing 1 byte more then you allocated at the moment.